# Regex for a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, regex, textbox

I am trying to remove the last entered letter in a texbox. I am using a Regex to determine if the entry is valid. However, the code I have only checks the first character, and stops after that. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I want the user to be able to input as many numbers as they want (including negative numbers).

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox_Gen_Offset_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex("[-+]?[0-9]*");

    if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox_Gen_Offset.Text))
    {
        UpdateTotal();
    }
    else
    {
        if (textBox_Gen_Offset.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBox_Gen_Offset.Text = textBox_Gen_Offset.Text.Substring(0, textBox_Gen_Offset.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is naïve - it assumes the invalid character will be entered at the last position. Consider the case where there is an existing value of `500` and I add a character at position 1: `5d00`.

Comment: Why don't you do this with jQuery? Is it really necessary to POST the page every time the textbox value is changed?

Comment: @SmartDev, where do you get the idea that this is ASP?  Could just as easily be winforms.

Comment: You may also be interested in [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: I need to verify that the user enters integer values per input. I am updating a Label based on the input (Acting like a calculator). The label is being updated as the user types in the value. This is not ASP, it is C#. Btw, nice catch SpikeX...I will have to come up with a solution for that scenario.

Comment: I don't know C# much, but can't you validate keypress activity ?

Comment: int.TryParse() did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't, but are notified of textbox change notifications (EN_CHANGED or something), you can either take out the offending character, or take out all past the offending character. Both ways using regex.

Comment: And `int.TryParse()` is just a atoi function. How that did the trick is a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on regex, but you could check if entered data is numeric by trying to parse is as an int or a double (for integers or floating point numbers respectively).

```
        int intInTheBox;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox_Gen_Offset.Text, out intInTheBox))
        {
            //Do stuff if it's an int
        }

        double doubleInTheBox;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox_Gen_Offset.Text, out doubleInTheBox))
        {
            //Do stuff if it's a double
        }
```

Comment: For reference, if you're wanting to handle non-whole numbers that this won't work. You'll need to do `double.TryParse()` rather than `int.TryParse()`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the text above the code, but thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my answer with a double.TryParse.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to comment on it because although OP didn't have any code that pointed towards including decimals, someone might still see this later. :)